# How to override default drag&drop cursors when the darg source is outside my application

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

In **Drag&Drop**, if I want to customize the cursors, I can subscribe to `GiveFeedback` on the drag source and set `e.UseDefaultCursors = false`, and the render the content I want.

But that only work if the drag source is my application. If I want to do the same when dragging files from explorer, for example, I can not subscribe to that event because I only have access to the drop target and not to the drag source.

Is there any other way to disable the built in cursors and copy and link signs so I can render my own in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... this probably wont help at all (i hope it does somehow) but in visual basic, using a language in the .NET Framework, when creating a form, there is an option for drag and drop to disable it, so whatever compiler your using, there maybe some sort of option in there.

I would  look specifically at what you are working with and read up on the drag and dropping, so maybe something to do with a form/GUI.

I hope this has helped in some way, if not, i apologize and gl.